# Robustness of Automatic updates against crashes

Tags: updates, dpkg, unattended-upgrades

If my Ubuntu is installing automatic updates and my computer crashes and I have to do a forced reboot, the automatic updates are repaired after booting the computer?

Answer (score 0):

It depends where in the process it crashed.

In the next boot run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If there's any problem APT will tell you in an error message. Follow the instruction given in the same message.

Comment: Thank you. But can you give a reference of the fact that APT will tell me that there is an error?